# How many bytes does a file called 'file.txt' with the text "test" take?

Tags: byte

I have a file on my my desktop called 'file.txt' and it contains the text "test".
When i right click the file go to properties, and view the size it says 4 bytes.
This makes sense because 4 characters = 4 bytes, but the file is called file.txt so this does take some space right? 
It only says the file takes 4 bytes and nothing more. 
I have tried searching on the web but i could not find a answer to this question.
So how many bytes does a file called 'file.txt' with the text "test" actually take?

Answer (score 1):

The size of a file is given by its content. In your case "test" is 4 chars in length = 4 Bytes. Obviously you will end up with this size regardless of the filename.

The name of a file is stored into directory information structure, which depends entirely on the filesystem in question. For more information on this topic you can consult https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117325/where-are-filenames-stored-on-a-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS. The OS does not store file on a byte by byte basis. A file has to fit into one or more *blocks*. The most common block size is 4KB. thus your file will take up 1 block on the HDD, whatever that block size is on your specific system. As to where the filename is stored, that depends on your filesystem. FAT, NTFS, ext3, HFS, etc. all have lookup tables/structures to store the name and other metadata. The details are outside the scope of this answer